# Generate dates using microsoft graph api for outlook events

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I am getting recurrence pattern from microsoft graph api . I need to generate dates in code on the basis of recurrence pattern details which it gives me.

This is the pattern which I am getting

```
"recurrence": {
    "pattern": {
      "type": "relativeMonthly",
      "interval": 1,
      "month": 0,
      "dayOfMonth": 0,
      "daysOfWeek": [
        "wednesday"
      ],
      "firstDayOfWeek": "sunday",
      "index": "third"
    },
    "range": {
      "type": "endDate",
      "startDate": "2023-12-20T00:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate": "2024-12-20T23:59:00.000Z",
      "recurrenceTimeZone": "India Standard Time",
      "numberOfOccurrences": 0
    }
  }
```

this is my code

```
     case "relativeMonthly":
            if (pattern.daysOfWeek && pattern.daysOfWeek.length > 0) {
                var days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
                var day = days.indexOf(dayName.toLowerCase());
                var nextOccurrence = findNthDayOfMonth(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), day, pattern.index);
                newDate = new Date(nextOccurrence);
            } else {
                newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + pattern.interval);
            }
            break;

 function findNthDayOfMonth(year, month, dayOfWeek, nthOccurrence) {
        // Create a date object at the beginning of the target month
        let date = new Date(year, month, 1);

        // Find the first occurrence of the day of the week
        let firstDayOccurrence = (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7;
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + firstDayOccurrence);

        // Adjust to the nth occurrence
        let daysToAdd = (nthOccurrence - 1) * 7;
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysToAdd);

        return date;
    }
```

my code is not giving me correct dates here for example for above pattern the date should be 20th june 2024 but its giving me 17th june which should not be the case here and it is giving me wrong dates constantly.

Need help with correct code.

Comment: `let daysToAdd = ("third" - 1) * 7` probably does not do what you intend.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I know but what is the logical generalized solution for it I am stuck in the logical solution of the problem.